# Why do long results from Git commands kill my PowerShell prompt?

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I am using Git Shell (the  module for PowerShell) on Windows. It's the one that got installed when I installed Git for Windows. When I run a command that results in a  lot of text such as `git log` I get a page of results and then a ":" at the bottom of the screen. I guess it's a continuation prompt because I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and get another screen of data. I can't usually recover to a normal prompt after this happens though. I get the text `(END)` at the bottom of the shell and it looks like it's masking the first few characters of whatever command I try to type and it even seems to act a little sporadic. I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Press the `Q` key for Quit. You can do this when at the END or when you see the `:`.

Comment: Incidentally you might be interested in [posh-git (PowerShell Git)](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

Comment: @vcsjones, thank you.  I was having to close my powershell console.

Comment: Sometimes `q` just doesn't work in PowerShell for unexplained (as of yet) reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several of the git commands use a pager to allow you to view one screen full of information at a time.  The one that come with git is usually `less` ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29)).  You can visit the link for common commands, but as you've found the most important is `q` to quit to get back to the command prompt.  The next most useful one I've found is <kbd>space</kbd> to move to the next screen full.

You can change the pager used if you like in the git config file's `core.pager` field.

Comment: You can also limit the results you get from git log by using the { git log --pretty=oneline } command

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the existing answers, the normal "windows" pager is `more.com`, which is usually referenced from `cmd` as simply `more`, but hidden by the function `more` with similar functionality in `PowerShell`. If you set

```
git config --global core.pager more.com
```

your problems should go away (although at the cost of features that exist in less but not more).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I would mention that git also provides a --no-pager option for you to leverage as well.

```
git --no-pager log
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: That's new to me and I appreciate it.